# Where condition equal true and Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, where-clause

I've been looking for an answer but I couldn't find anything to help me. I get this error

> Nullable object must have a value.

My request is:

```
from e in dc.tblElements 
where
    e.IsUnique &&
    (e.TypeID == 2) &&     
    (categoryId != null ? e.CategoryId.Value == categoryId.Value : true) &&
    ((e.Name.Contains(keyword)) ||
    (e.Keywords.Contains(keyword)))
select e
```

The third line of the `where` condition is the problem (`categoryId`). If `categoryId` has a value, it works but not when it is `null`. However, I replaced this line with `true` and it works as well. I can't understand what is the problem here.

in my table CategoryId can be null so I tried:

```
(categoryId.HasValue && e.CategoryId.HasValue ? e.CategoryId.Value == categoryId.Value : true)
```

What I want to do: I want to select all the elements of this table depending on the where condition. categoryId comes from a drop down so if the default value is still selected when the user does the request, I want to display all the elements no matter what the category.

Comment: You don't need that line. There's no need for 'catch-all" parameters in LINQ, you can just add another `Where()` clause as necessary

Comment: Could you describe, *in plain English*, what you want?

Comment: I edited the topic. @Panagiotis Kanavos can you explain a bit more your idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be good with just comparing your two variables:

```
e.CategoryId == categoryId
```

If you want special treatment of one being NULL, maybe because you want that to be a special case where NULL matches *everything* instead of just another NULL, you can add that:

```
e.CategoryId == categoryId || !e.CategoryId.HasValue || !categoryId.HasValue
```

---

Your problem with your statement is that you access `.Value`. Yes, if you would run the code with Linq-To-Objects in memory, it would work because the compiler will only run the code of one branch of your if-statement (ternary operator, I know, but you get what I mean). But for a database, there needs to be a statement prepared. That statement needs to be there in full, it does not use any short-circuiting. So the statement builder *will* access both your branches to build that statement for the database and one of those branches will fail because it accesses `.Value` although there is none.

Comment: In your case (2nd line), if categoryId = 5 I will get, all the elems with categoryId = 5 but also all the elems with no category. When categoryId has a value, I just want the elems with this categoryId. Am I right?

Comment: @TylerDurden I cannot tell you what you *want*. That's why I asked in the comments to your question. If you can describe what you *want* to happen, we can help you with that.

Comment: @nvoigt if that was SQL it would be the catch-all parameter antipattern. If `categoryId` is null the right option is to *not* add the condition at all.

Comment: @nvoigt Okay I think, I understand what you mean. Thank you for your reply and explanations. I changed the line by `((categoryId.HasValue) ? (p.CategoryID == categoryId) : true)` and it is working like a charm.

Comment: @TylerDurden better check the performance first. The query optimizer will cache the plan used for the *first* execution. If the first execution had a null CategoryID parameter it probably won't use any indexes that include `categoryId`. This could harm performance for calls with a non-null CategoryID parameter, eg by performing a table scan instead of a seek on an indext that contains CategoryID

Answer (score 1):

Make CategoryId as nullable type and try.

```
Nullable<int> CategoryId = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to implement a "catch-all" `categoryId` parameter. That's an *anti-pattern* in SQL and a strong smell that can lead to bad performance.

In LINQ, it's not necessary since you can add `.Where()` conditions just by adding another `.Where()` call to your query, eg :

```
var query = from e in dc.tblElements 
            where
                e.IsUnique &&
                e.TypeID == 2 &&     
                ( e.Name.Contains(keyword) ||
                  e.Keywords.Contains(keyword) )
            select e;
if (categoryId.HasValue)
{
    query=query.Where(e.CategoryId == categoryId);
}
```

You can use this to add multiple conditions at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from e in dc.tblElements 
where
    e.IsUnique &&
    (e.TypeID == 2) &&     
    (categoryId.HasValue && e.CategoryId.Value == categoryId.Value) &&
    ((e.Name.Contains(keyword)) ||
    (e.Keywords.Contains(keyword)))
select e
```